# How do you make n number of lists with k number of integers in python?

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to make a lottery program where you can play multiple "rows". I have managed to make it in a way that you can pick one row of numbers and the program picks the winning numbers and checks the results.

So the question is how can the player choose multiple sets of numbers? All numbers have to be unique in a particular set but different sets can have duplicates.

For example this is okay: [1,2,4,6,9] , [1,2, 5,11,16]

This isn't [1,1,2,3,3] , [4,4,6,8,11]

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far ? It would be helpful

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to ask a question according to the [ask] page. We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is on-topic here by visiting the [help/on-topic]; asking us to write the program for you, suggestions, and external links are off-topic. Please share a [mre] of what you have so we can see where you are stuck.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved using the `random.sample()` function.

```
import random

# Set the number of rows
number_of_rows = 3

# Set how many numbers needed for each row
count = 5

# Set the possible numbers for the lottery
numbers = [x for x in range(50)]

# Empty result array
result = []

# Take a sample of the numbers for each of the desired rows
for row in range(0, number_of_rows):
    result += [random.sample(numbers, count)]

# Print result
print(result)
```

Note that this example returns the desired number of rows and their numbers as an array of arrays. There are of course other ways to achieve this.